# How should be a dynamic website structured?

Tags: php, html, mysql, content-management-system

I have wrote my own CMS in PHP. It is quite simple, but it does not permit me to do some things, like the redirect with `header()` from dynamic page.
Here is its structure (very simplified):

```
<?php
$db = new PDO...
try {
    //getting page info from database (by $_GET['id'])
    //and put results into $pageInfo
    $stmt->prepare
//.. catch etc...
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title><?=$pageInfo['title'];?></title></head>
<body>
<?php
//this file below cannot contain a php redirect, because headers are already sent
include($pageInfo['content_path']);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

There is one page that is dynamic and can display other pages by changing the value of the get parameter id.
The included content often contains PHP scripts.

I have looked around the internet but I don't know how to resolve this issue.
May I create a `header.html` and a `footer.html` and include them into every page? But if I include the header file before including the content doesn't it send headers? How?

Really sorry if this question seems stupid, but I don't know how to do it. I haven't someone that teaches me, so I have to learn all by myself but for some things I don't know where to look.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You **can not** send headers when the output has started, at that time it's too late. including other PHP files in your scripts is fine, and not a problem at all

Comment: try adding @ob_start() at the begining of ur code

Comment: you're fishing for opinions, which are explicitly off-topic. There is no one "right way" to build a site. there's only opinions.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: @MarcB but there are coding standards

Comment: and the nice thing about standards is that there's so many to choose from. there isn't ONE standard, and choosing which one you follow is also opinion.

Comment: Content output should always happen at the very last of the script. When outputting content, you should already know that you do not require a redirect or something alike. Including static html code inside the output section should be okay, but everything php functionality should be included at the top of the script. I disencourage the use of output buffering if not absolutely needed, because it obscures the actions of the script and makes it more difficult to debug and modify by others.

Comment: @syck so, how can I do that?

Comment: Think and act accordingly. Sorry, unspecific questions provoke unspecific answers.

Comment: @syck where was I unspecify? I have already tought that I may do the output at the end, but I don't know how. Because I need to execute the content before the output, but I also need to put a header before the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way is to have the application separated into several parts, one part that executes code (Controller or core) and another one that displays something (View or template).

For example in MVC (Model/View/Controller), your single page would be just a dispatcher that calls a controller, the controller executes PHP-code, and fetches some data by using the second part, the model, and finally calls a template to display the data.

In your example you could start by including two files for each call, one that contains only PHP-code and fetches all data, and after that one that contains a html-template with variables and only very simple code that is needed to display the data. You can then do redirects and exit in the php-part (controller).